# How to remove channels in Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

How do you remove a channel, or at least instruct Conda to not abort if one of the channel URLs is down?

I was testing a buggy tool, which provided a Conda repo at `https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/linux-64`, but now that repo is offline, and now all calls to `conda create --prefix=./cenv -y python=3.7` fail with the message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE for url <https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: 00:02.470723

A remote server error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.

A 500-type error (e.g. 500, 501, 502, 503, etc.) indicates the server failed to
fulfill a valid request.  The problem may be spurious, and will resolve itself if you
try your request again.  If the problem persists, consider notifying the maintainer
of the remote server.
```

I'm not using this channel in my create command, so I don't know why Conda fails rather than ignore it. How do I allow Conda to continue or purge the channel?

I tried removing the channel by running:

```
conda config --remove channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda
```

outputs the error:

```
CondaKeyError: 'channels': 'https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda' is not in the 'channels' key of the config file
```

Edit: My `conda info` is:

```
     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/myuser/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/myuser/miniconda3/.condarc
                          /home/myuser/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /home/myuser/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/linux-64
                          https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/noarch
          package cache : /home/myuser/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/myuser/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/myuser/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.15.0-64-generic ubuntu/18.04.3 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Running either:

```
conda config --remove channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/linux-64
conda config --remove channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/noarch
```

outputs the error:

```
CondaKeyError: 'channels': 'https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/<name>' is not in the 'channels' key of the config file
```

These ire the contents of my `.condarc`:

```
$ cat ~/.condarc 
show_channel_urls: true
auto_activate_base: false
channels:
  - defaults
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `conda info`?

Answer (score 4):

```sh
conda config --remove channels https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda
```

works in my test.

Another way is to open `.condarc` files under your `$HOME` directory, and comment out the corresponding channel line.

Comment: ```conda config --show-sources``` show the exact location of .condarc

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, conda differentiates between channel names and channel URLs. I.e. `conda info` will output something like:

```
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

whereas `conda config --show channels` will output

```
channels:
  - defaults
```

I think you have to remove channels by their name, not by their URL.

Also in your home directory there should be a file called `.condarc` which contains all the user's custom settings, including channels. You could just open that file with a text editor and delete the channel from there.

And lastly there is the flag `--override-channels` which ignores the default channel as well as all channels set in your `.condarc`, meaning with this flag you have to manually specify the channels you want to use in your conda command.