# How to remove a conda channel that was added by conda install, but does not appear in conda info or --show channels?

Tags: conda, miniconda

The closest to my problem is [How to remove channels in Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368839/how-to-remove-channels-in-conda) but it's not an exact duplicate as the error is not the same and none of the proposed solutions work in my case.

I installed an older version of Pytorch by running

```
conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-lightning/1.6.1/download/noarch/pytorch-lightning-1.6.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
```

Since then, when trying to install another package, such as

```
conda install -c conda-forge imgaug
```

I get an error

```
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
 - pytorch
 - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-lightning/1.6.1/download
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for channel conda-forge/pytorch-lightning/1.6.1/download <https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-lightning/1.6.1/download>

The channel is not accessible or is invalid.

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

But when I run `conda config --show channels` all I get is

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
```

and when I run `conda config --show-sources` I get:

```
==> /root/.condarc <==
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
solver: libmamba

==> cmd_line <==
debug: False
json: False
```

`conda info` gives me

```
     active environment : my_env
    active env location : /root/miniconda3/envs/my_env
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : /root/.condarc
          conda version : 23.7.4
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.18.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=11.3=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /root/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /root/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
          package cache : /root/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/miniconda3/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.7.4 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.9.18 Linux/5.4.0-66-generic ubuntu/20.04.5 glibc/2.31 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.7.0 libmambapy/1.5.1
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

and `/root/.condarc` only contains

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
solver: libmamba
```

---

What can I do to make `conda` not try to use `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-lightning/1.6.1/download` as a channel?